# Powershell profile "on exit" event?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to automatically do some clean up tasks when the PowerShell session quits. So for example in my profile file I start a process which needs to run in the background for quite a lot of tasks and I would like to automatically close that process when I close the console.

Is there some function the PowerShell automatically calls when closing the session as it does with `prompt` when displaying the prompt?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is the [`Register-EngineEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent) cmdlet which you can use to attach an event handler to the `Exiting` event:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { ... }
```

Note however, that this event will not be fired if you close the console window.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine but I mostly close my shell without typing `exit` explicitely. Maybe someone else has an idea, otherwise I need to get used to the `exit` ;)

Comment: Btw. you should add the parameter `-SupportEvent` to prevent PowerShell from printing out the event data whenever the shell starts. -- Or pipe it to `Out-Null`.

Comment: @poke: I'm using the following little snippet in my profile: `Invoke-Expression "function $([char]4) { exit }"` this allows me to exit PowerShell by pressing Ctrl+D and Enter. Not perfect but short enough to avoid going for the X button.

Comment: Whoah, that's a nice idea! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I feel `exit` is easier than click x button.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of how to on exit event. In this case, saving the History of commands on to a file, and maybe stored in a $Profile.

> To automatically export the previous commands to a file at the end of
> a PowerShell session, you can bind the script to the PoSh session
> termination event (!! The session must be necessarily ended with the
> exit command, rather than simply closing the PowerShell
> window):
>
> ```
> $HistFile = Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath('UserProfile')) .ps_history
> Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { Get-History | Export-Clixml $HistFile } | out-null
> if (Test-path $HistFile) { Import-Clixml $HistFile | Add-History }
> ```

Quoted from https://woshub.com/powershell-commands-history/