# How can I clean up temporary files when I close a PowerShell console?

Tags: powershell

I have some PowerShell scripts which create temporary files.  I want to keep them around until the user closes the console.  Is there a way to pick up on the console window closing and run a clean-up script or script-block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "Register-EngineEvent" cmdlet:

- [Powershell profile "on exit" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436510/powershell-profile-on-exit-event)
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849967.aspx

PS:

You can also use `Register-ObjectEvent` and `Register-CimIndicationEvent` cmdlets to react to .NET and WMI events, respectively:

http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/WguS/create-and-respond-to-custom-events

Comment: Thanks very much - it was spot on!