# Persist current directory between PowerShell sessions

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to make PowerShell Console remember the current directory from the last time it was run and use that as the default location for the next instance?

eg.

- Open PowerShell Console
- `Set-Location c:\tmp`
- Close PowerShell
- Open PowerShell Console
- `Get-Location` returns `c:\tmp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Shawn and @Mathias for both giving great answers. I ended up combining your approaches to come up with the following:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
    Write-Warning "Saving current location"
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LocationMemory", (Get-Location).Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
} | Out-Null

$lastPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LocationMemory",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)

if (($lastPath -ne $null) -and (Test-Path $lastPath)) {
    Set-Location $lastPath
}
```

There is around a 4 second delay for me when `SetEnvironmentVariable` is called, which is why I added the `Write-Warning` (otherwise you might think that the console window isn't closing after you exited or clicked on the Close Window control)

Comment: I will but in this case it would be nicer if I could accept both other answers as correct instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the `prompt` function to save location changes to a user environment variable:

```
$Function:prompt = {
    if([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LocationMemory",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User) -ne $PWD){
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LocationMemory",$PWD,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
    }
    "PS $($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($NestedPromptLevel + 1))"
}
```

And then check if the environment variable exists and is valid when powershell starts

```
if(($LastLocation = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LocationMemory",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User))){
    if((Test-Path $LastLocation -PathType Container)){
        Set-Location $LastLocation
    }
}
```

Put both snippets in your profile to make it work. You probably want to limit it to `$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost`

Comment: I like the idea of using an environment variable to save the value

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is perfect but testing on my machine it seems to work. First check out [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2436510/847990), this is the icing of the cake. You are basically going to have to log the current path of your session through an exiting event with PowerShell.

You can add this bit of code to your `$PROFILE` so it will always register the exit event and then set the path.

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action {(Get-Location).Path | Out-File 'C:\Users\wshaw\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\LastPath.txt' -Force}
$lastPath = 'C:\Users\wshaw\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\LastPath.txt'
if (Test-Path $lastPath) {
    Set-Location (Get-Content $lastPath)
}
```

Comment: I like the use of the event to only run the 'save' code at the appropriate time

Answer (score 0):

1. The other solutions ignore when PowerShell is intentionally opened to a specific folder such as by clicking 'Open in Terminal' in a folder, or when an IDE opens PowerShell to a project folder.
2. The most recent answer mentions a 4 second delay every time saving an environment variable. This is because as the last step of `SetEnvironmentVariable`, Windows sequentially notifies all other apps of the environment change and there is a 1 second timeout delay for each app that doesn't process it. The code below saves to a file instead.

An enhancement to only restore if PowerShell would otherwise open in the default folder (userprofile on my system), and saving to a file in %LOCALAPPDATA%:

```
if ((Get-Location).Path -eq $env:USERPROFILE) {
    $lastPathFile = Join-Path (Join-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA 'PowerShell') 'LastPath.txt'
    if (Test-Path $lastPathFile) { Push-Location (Get-Content $lastPathFile) }
}

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent {
    $lastPathFile = Join-Path (Join-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA 'PowerShell') 'LastPath.txt'
    (Get-Location).Path | Out-File (New-Item $lastPathFile -Force)
}
```

Add the above code [to your PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/creating-profiles).

All the most recent answers (including this) save the value if exited with the `exit` command or if you [bind Ctrl+w or Ctrl+d etc. to DeleteCharOrExit](https://superuser.com/a/1388343/1853603)—but not if closed with the windows close button or Alt-F4: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000

Answer (score 0):

I use PowerShell on a USB drive so I decided to append my last location to the file for History (using the same command on `exit`.

```PowerShell
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
  $PWD = (Resolve-Path .).Path
  $PWD = "cd `"$PWD`""
  Add-Content -Path (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath -Value "$PWD" }
```